# My tableview does not reload when pressed back and searched again

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

So i have a search page. The word the user searches is passed to the next view controller. Now instead to using prepare for segue and passing the value, I store it as a global variable and just to a performSegue.

The problem is when I go back using the back button of the navigation controller, the new data doesn't reload when I click on search. It shows the old data.

Link of the images is given below. Now 1st one is a search for Rahul. It shows the correct result now the next is when I go back and search for Rohan it shows the result for Rahul itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/irUwo.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fthOm.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7wKJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Once perform to the result view controller, ask your main thread to call tableView.reloadData() after you received the new global value you pass. If this can't help you, please provide your code so that we could help you by clearly understand your situation.